# Use multiple celery results as arguments for a subsequent task

Tags: python, celery

I'm currently going through the Celery user guide which has [the following example](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#the-primitives):

```py
# ((4 + 16) * 2 + 4) * 8
>>> c2 = (add.s(4, 16) | mul.s(2) | (add.s(4) | mul.s(8)))
>>> res = c2()
>>> res.get()
352
```

But this example only uses one partial result at a time. My question is whether it is possible to use several, with the same primitive tasks (`add` and `mul`), e.g.:

```py
# ((4 + 16) * (2 + 4)) * 8
>>> c2 = ???
>>> res = c2()
>>> res.get()
960
```

Below are my tries so far:

```py
# TypeError: mul() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
>>> c2 = (add.s(4, 16) | (add.si(2, 4) | mul.s()) | mul.s(8))

# Works, but needs to implement a new "prod" task
>>> c2 = (group(add.s(4, 16), add.s(2, 4)) | prod.s() | mul.s(8))
```

Where `prod` is simply:

```py
@app.task
def prod(xs):
    return functools.reduce((lambda x, y: x * y), xs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve multiple celery results from multiple tasks at once by using [groups](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#groups). However as you already found out, it returns a single object only which is a sequence e.g. `[20, 6]`. Since it is only a single object (which is a sequence containing 2 items), thus you have to unwrap the sequence first before you can map it to the existing definitions of `add` or `mul` as what you did with your new `prod` task.

An alternative I can think of without using the intermediate `prod` task is by separating them into 2 chains.

```
>>> c1 = group(add.s(4, 16), add.s(2, 4))  # 4+16, 2+4
>>> c2 = mul.s(*c1().get()) | mul.s(8)  # (20 * 6) * 8
>>> c2().get()
960
```

Or you can choose to just update the implementation of `mul` to instead accept `*args` and handle the scenario of passing in a sequence e.g. `list` so that the call can either be `mul(20, 6)` or `mul([20, 6])`, allowing you to directly perform `(group(add.s(4, 16), add.s(2, 4)) | mul.s() | mul.s(8))`.

```
@app.task
def mul(*args):
    if len(args) == 1 and isinstance(args[0], collections.abc.Sequence):
        args = args[0]
    return functools.reduce((lambda x, y: x * y), args)
```

Comment: Unfortunately the first suggestion does two synchronizations with the client code (not taking advantage of Celery scheduling), and the second has the same flaw as the `prod` solution: it needs to modify the `tasks` code. If I understand correctly, this means that this code needs to be shipped to the worker machines, and the workers then restarted. This question is around a toy example to find how to build and then combine a small subset of generic functions into a complete computation graph using Celery's canvas.